# Getting Invalid Format For Joda Date

Tags: java, jodatime

I am trying to convert a Joda Date time to a string in "MM/dd/yyyy" so I can do a `sendKeys`. 
Below is the code I am using:

```
            //Enter an IRB Expiration Date
            WebElement irbExpCP = driver.findElement(By.id("irbExpDate"));
            irbExpCP.click();
            String irbDate = dt.now().plusYears(5).toString();
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String irbDate2 = formatter.parseLocalDate(irbDate).toString();

            irbExpCP.sendKeys(irbDate2);
```

When I run through this I am getting the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2018-05-30" is malformed at "18-05-30"'

I have looked at several different questions here as well as the joda DateTimeFormatter page to no avail. I just need to have the date in the `MM/dd/yyyy` format. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using it the way round. This should work better:

```
DateTime irbDate = dt.now().plusYears(5);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
String irbDate2 = formatter.print(irbDate);
```